# Count how many days log return between 0.01 and 0.015

Tags: r

I'm a newbie to R. I have a data frame in R of log returns for one year of adjusted close stock prices. Here's a sample of the data:

```
data <- read.csv("AAPL-Data.csv")
df <- data.frame(Log_Returns = diff(log(Ad(data))))
    Log_Returns 
1  6.326076e-03
2  1.824152e-02
3  3.683450e-03
4  -4.434373e-03
5  -2.394487e-02
6  1.729473e-03
7  -5.121480e-04
8  5.937422e-03
9  -4.401654e-03
10  6.373016e-03
11 3.520299e-02
12 2.225889e-02
13 1.381963e-02
14 -1.280049e-02
15 7.283613e-03
16 2.577874e-02
17 1.009374e-02
18 3.208668e-03
19 8.147066e-03
20 -2.044707e-03
```

I need to use R to count how many days log return between 0.01 and 0.015. Not sure how to go about doing this without using `view(df)` to look at the table and counting the results manually. Is there a function I can use to do this?

Comment: `length(df[df$Log_Returns > 0.01 & df$Log_Returns < 0.015, 'Log_Returns'])`

Comment: Thanks! This worked. Simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum(df$Log_Returns >= 0.01 & df$Log_Returns <= 0.015)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `tidyverse` approach.

```
require(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  summarise(between = sum(Log_Returns > 0.01 & Log_Returns < 0.015), 
            notBetween = sum(!(Log_Returns > 0.01 & Log_Returns < 0.015)))
```

Result:

```
  between notBetween
1       2         18
```

Data:

```
df <- read.csv(text =  "Log_Returns 
             6.326076e-03
             1.824152e-02
              3.683450e-03
              -4.434373e-03
              -2.394487e-02
              1.729473e-03
              -5.121480e-04
              5.937422e-03
              -4.401654e-03
              6.373016e-03
             3.520299e-02
             2.225889e-02
             1.381963e-02
             -1.280049e-02
             7.283613e-03
             2.577874e-02
             1.009374e-02
             3.208668e-03
             8.147066e-03
             -2.044707e-03")
```